# Multiple Excel Sheets into multiple Query connections in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

How to transform multiple Excel sheets to Mutiple Power query connections automatically in Excel.

Lets Say, If there are 2 sheets in Excel, the 2 sheets should be loaded into Query Connections Automatically,

Any body has any work around to achieve this.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the query connections have to be in the original workbook or are you trying to create a way to read and combine multiple files with multiple tabs?

Comment: i'm giving an external Excel file using it's path reference into the Macro file which i'm using,

Comment: I'm able to combine the Data, But the problem is the Data will in Different Sheet is not similar, some of the key Columns are Same, but the other important Columns are not in the Same order.

Comment: You can read in all tabs from an external file(s) in powerquery then just filter to the desired tab results. Is that what you want?

Comment: I need all Tabs to be combined. based on the certain columns. but the columns are not in the same order

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps at all
It combines all workbooks and all tabs on those workbooks regardless of column order, and you can filter down to tabname and workbook name afterwards

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```